# Class Rolling Dice program

Tags: c++

I need to write C program for rolling dice using class Dice. The main requirement is that I need to use this main, editing it:

```
int main()
{
      Dice* ptrDice;
             ???
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
           ????                // roll the 5 dice
           ????                // print the outcome
      }
}
```

I just cannot get how to use pointers here. Can anyone help, pls?!

Here is my code but it's not working :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Dice{
  public:
    Dice();
    int getNums();
    void Roll();
  private:
    int nNums;
};

Dice::Dice(){
    nNums=5;
}
int Dice::getNums()
{
    return nNums;
}
void Dice::Roll()
{
    nNums = rand()%6 + 1;
}

int main()
{
      Dice* ptrDice = new Dice;
      ptrDice -> getNums();
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
       getNums[i] = rand()%6 + 1;                // roll the 5 dice
       cout << "You rolled: ";
       cout << ptrDice->getNums() << setw(4);
       cout << endl;                             // print the outcome
      }
}
```

My main trouble is to use that ptrDice and printing it in main function, I guess!

Comment: Why not read the lecture notes?

Comment: Other than perfect random number generation, I think you have all the implementation. But you are not calling the necessary member functions correctly. For example, think of why `Dice::Roll()` exists ?

Comment: You need to write a *C++* program. The two are not the same.

Comment: It looks like the program is still in transition, `getNums[i]` array is not declared anywhere but that looks like old code.

Comment: Replace the line `getNums[i] = rand()%6 + 1` with `ptrDice->Roll()`. And add `delete ptrDice` at the bottom right before exiting `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be.

A simple Dice object needs no data members and only one member function. If you're using the rand() function, the constructor should seed the random number generator with srand(seed). The Roll() function should return the number rolled as an int. You don't need the getNums() function at all, which will only return 5 as your class is defined.

```
class Dice() {
public:
    int roll() { return rand() % 6 + 1; }
};
```

...

```
int main() {
    Dice* ptrDice = new Dice;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        cout << "You rolled" << ptrDice->roll() << '\n';
    }
    delete ptrDice;
}
```

You could expand this class to simulate multiple dice with any number of sides. Then you could use integer data members to retain the number of dice and their number of sides.